# WebSocket Connection is not closing using SocketRocket

Tags: objective-c, connection, websocket, socketrocket

I use the SocketRocket library for Objective-C to connect to a websocket:

```
-(void)open {

if( self.webSocket ) {
    [self.webSocket close];
    self.webSocket.delegate = nil;
}

self.webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://192.168.0.254:5864"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20]];
self.webSocket.delegate = self;
[self.webSocket open];
}
```

Opening the connection works totally fine. The delegate is called after the connection was established.

```
-(void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket {

NSLog(@"WebSocket is open");

}
```

But when I want to close the connection, nothing happens.

```
-(void)close {

if( !self.webSocket )
    return;

[self.webSocket close];
self.webSocket.delegate = nil;

}
```

The delegate for successfully closing the connection is not called. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: what is this condition returns "if( !self.webSocket )" ?

Comment: that means that the websocket schouldn´t be closed if it is nil, because then it isn´t open anyways

Comment: I am always getting this error and Test to Speech getting Audio interruption, WebSocket closed with reason[1000]: Manually terminating socket connection Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey @AnilkumariOSdeveloper. Sorry I have no clue. Please ask a new question on SO regarding your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that the delegate is never called, because the websocket is never really closed. The closing of the websocket in the SRWebSocket happens in the method **pumpWriting** like this:

```
if (_closeWhenFinishedWriting && 
    _outputBuffer.length - _outputBufferOffset == 0 && 
    (_inputStream.streamStatus != NSStreamStatusNotOpen &&
     _inputStream.streamStatus != NSStreamStatusClosed) &&
    !_sentClose) {
    _sentClose = YES;

    [_outputStream close];
    [_inputStream close];

    if (!_failed) {
        dispatch_async(_callbackQueue, ^{
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webSocket:didCloseWithCode:reason:wasClean:)]) {
                [self.delegate webSocket:self didCloseWithCode:_closeCode reason:_closeReason wasClean:YES];
            }
        });
    }

    _selfRetain = nil;

    NSLog(@" Is really closed and released ");
}
else {

    NSLog(@" Is NOT closed and released ");
}
```

All streams and an object to retain the websocket are closed or deleted there. As long as they are still open, the socket won´t be closed appropriately. But the closing never happened in my program, because when I tried to close the websocket, **_closeWhenFinishedWriting** was always NO.

This boolean is only set once in the **disconnect** method.

```
- (void)_disconnect;
{

assert(dispatch_get_current_queue() == _workQueue);
SRFastLog(@"Trying to disconnect");
_closeWhenFinishedWriting = YES;
[self _pumpWriting];

}
```

But when calling the **closeWithCode** method in SRWebSocket, **disconnect** is only called in one case and that is, if the websocket is in the connecting state.

```
BOOL wasConnecting = self.readyState == SR_CONNECTING;

SRFastLog(@"Closing with code %d reason %@", code, reason);
dispatch_async(_workQueue, ^{

    if (wasConnecting) {
        [self _disconnect];
        return;
    }
```

This means, if the socket is in another state, the websocket will never really close. One workaround is to always call the **disconnect** method. At least it worked for me and everything seems to be alright.

If anyone has an idea, why SRWebSocket is implemented like that, please leave a comment for this answer and help me out.

Comment: I am not finding disconnect method anywhere in whole code of SRWebSocket

Comment: I am always getting this error and Test to Speech getting Audio interruption, WebSocket closed with reason[1000]: Manually terminating socket connection Any suggestions?

Comment: @Philip Otto Your answer is somewhat helpful but could you please send your class files of SRWebSocket? Having same problem and always prints: `Is NOT closed and released`

Comment: Hey @Nij. Sorry this is way too long ago. I hope you found a solution!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bug.
When calling close, the server echo's back the 'close' message.
It is received by SRWebSocket, however the _selfRetain is never set to nil, and the socket remains open (the streams are not closed) and we have a memory leak.
I have checked and observed this in the test chat app as well.
I made the following change:

```
-(BOOL)_innerPumpScanner {    
    BOOL didWork = NO;

    if (self.readyState >= SR_CLOSING) {
        [self _disconnect];  // <--- Added call to disconnect which releases _selfRetain
        return didWork;
    }
```

Now the socket closes, the instance is released, and the memory leak is gone.
The only thing that I am not sure of is if the delegate should be called when closing in this way. Will look into this.

Comment: Yeah you´re right. As I mentioned in my answer, the _disconnect has to be called to set the BOOL _closeWhenFinishedWriting to YES, so that the _selfRetain can be set to nil appropriately

Comment: Correct. There is the case when a server dies, the delegate won't be notified, and will just sit there. I made changes so the delegate gets notified. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/pull/106) if anyone wants to see the changes I made.

Comment: This issue has been address on GitHub, although the fix has not been merged. https://github.com/mediumbear/SocketRocket/commit/08afedbeb991edfda13aa675b5720c53ffaf7ef8

Comment: Yup - quite a lot of forks from that commit, from what I can see.

Comment: I am always getting this error and Test to Speech getting Audio interruption, WebSocket closed with reason[1000]: Manually terminating socket connection Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> Once an endpoint has both sent and received a Close control frame, that endpoint SHOULD *Close the WebSocket Connection* as defined in Section 7.1.1. ([RFC 6455 7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.2))

The SRWebSocket instance doesn't `_disconnect` here because that would close the TCP connection to the server *before* the client has received a Close control frame in response.  In fact, `_disconnect`ing here will tear down the TCP socket before the client can even send its own Close frame to the server, because `_disconnect` ultimately calls `_pumpWriting` before `closeWithCode:` can.  The server will probably respond gracefully enough, but it's nonconforming, and you won't be able to send situation-unique close codes while things are set up this way.

This is properly dealt with in `handleCloseWithData:`

```
if (self.readyState == SR_OPEN) {
    [self closeWithCode:1000 reason:nil];
}
dispatch_async(_workQueue, ^{
    [self _disconnect];
});
```

This block handles Close requests initiated by both the client and the server.  If the server sends the first Close frame, the method runs as per the sequence you laid out, ultimately ending up in `_pumpWriting` via `closeWithCode:`, where the client will respond with its own Close frame.  It then goes on to tear down the connection with that `_disconnect`.

When the client sends the frame first, `closeWithCode:` runs once without closing the TCP connection because `_closeWhenFinishedWriting` is still false.  This allows the server time to respond with its own Close frame, which would normally result in running `closeWithCode:` again, but for the following block at the top of that method:

```
if (self.readyState == SR_CLOSING || self.readyState == SR_CLOSED) {
    return;
}
```

Because the readyState is changed on the first iteration of `closeWithCode:`, this time it simply won't run.

emp's bug fix is necessary to make this work as intended, however: otherwise the Close frame from the server doesn't do anything.  The connection will still end, but dirtily, because the server (having both sent and received its frames) will break down the socket on its end, and the client will respond with an `NSStreamEventEndEncountered:`, which is normally reserved for stream errors caused by sudden losses of connectivity.  A better approach would be to determine why the frame never gets out of `_innerPumpScanner` to `handleCloseWIthData:`.  Another issue to keep in mind is that by default, `close` just calls `closeWithCode:` with an RFC-nonconforming code of -1.  This threw errors on my server until I changed it to send one of the accepted values.

**All that said**: your delegate method doesn't work because you're unsetting the delegate right after you call `close`.  Everything in `close` is inside an async block; there won't be a delegate left to call by the time you invoke `didCloseWithCode:` regardless of what else you do here.

Comment: I am always getting this error and Test to Speech getting Audio interruption,  WebSocket closed with reason[1000]: Manually terminating socket connection
Any suggestions?